# Why does the following validation code get stuck on the cin.ignore when I enter 1.w and go into an infinite loop when I enter w.1?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Why does the following validation code get stuck on the cin.ignore when I enter 
1.w and go into an infinite loop when I enter w.1?
I am trying to create code that validates numerical input. I have created the code from suggestions given on other posts, but I'm still having problems.

```
//The code is validation code used to check if input is numerical (float or integer). 
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits> // std::numeric_limits
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    string line;
    float amount=0;
    bool flag=true;

//while loop to check inputs
while (flag){ //check for valid numerical input
    cout << "Enter amount:";
    getline(cin>>amount,line);
//use the string find_first_not_of function to test for numerical input
    unsigned test = line.find_first_not_of('0123456789-.');

    if (test==std::string::npos){ //if input stream contains valid inputs
        cout << "WOW!" << endl;
        cout << "You entered " << line << endl;
        cout << "amount = " << amount << endl;
    }

    else{ //if input stream is invalid
        cin.clear();
        // Ignore to the end of line
        cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
  }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never set `flag` to `false`, so it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: `getline(cin >> amount, line);` should be `cin >> amount; getline(cin, line);`

Answer (score 3):

First, `'0123456789-.'` should be `"0123456789-."` (note the double quotes). The former is a multibyte character literal.

When you enter `1.w`:

- `1` gets extracted by `cin>>amount`.
- `.w` get extracted by `getline`
- the stream is empty, so `ignore` waits for inputs

When you enter `w.1`:

- `cin>>amount` fails, `failbit` gets set
- `getline` can't extract when stream is bad, so `line` stays empty
- `test` equals `npos`, so we never enter the `else` block to clear the stream
- repeat all over again